# how do i add a uiviewcontroller before the navigation controller when using the master-detail template and core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have tried almost everything i can think of to add a uiviewcontroller prior to the navigation controller but every time it crashes due to core data managed context method. I have attached the piece of code that is my problem as I can't remove the navigation controller from being the rootviewcontroller whilst using the core data.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
return YES;}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add another controller before the navigation controller, or just get rid of the navigation controller, so that MasterViewController is the window's root view controller?

Comment: Add another view controller prior to the navigation controller

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem.

1. Delete the above code from didFinishLaunch in the appdelegte
2. Import app delegate into view controller
3. add this code to view did load in view controller

   ```
   self.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

   if (self.managedObjectContext == nil) {
   self.managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
   }
   ```